# PHP 5.6 - Modify object in loop with if-statements updates latest only

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, silverstripe, php-5.6

In my system Cars and product category are a combination that has a EAN code. Every car can have several products catergory that have a different EAN code and I want to use the EAN code that belongs to that specific combination. I use a foreach to loop through all cars and get the right EAN code and put in in a Arraylist for the product category that it has but whenever I run my code only the latest EAN code will be used for all product categories that the car has.

**For example:**
Car 1 has 3 categories: cat1 has EAN 123, cat2 has EAN 324 and cat3 has EAN 543 but when I check the car 1 categories all EAN codes are set to 543.

The loop Im talking about:

```
    foreach($cars as $car) {
        if($car->Cat1 == 1) {
            $ean = koppelEan::get()->filter( array('ProductID' => 127, 'AutoTypeID' => $car->ID))->first();
            $car->EAN = $ean->EAN;

            self::$Cat1->add($car);
        }

        if($car->Cat2 == 1) {
            $ean = koppelEan::get()->filter( array('ProductID' => 126, 'AutoTypeID' => $car->ID))->first();
            $car->EAN = $ean->EAN;
            self::$Cat2->add($car);
        }

        if($car->Cat3 == 1) {
            $ean = koppelEan::get()->filter( array('ProductID' => 781, 'AutoTypeID' => $car->ID))->first();

            $car->EAN = $ean->EAN;
            self::$Cat3->add($car);
        }

        if($car->Cat4 == 1) {
            $ean = koppelEan::get()->filter( array('ProductID' => 2924, 'AutoTypeID' => $car->ID))->first();
            $car->EAN = $ean->EAN;
            self::$Cat4->add($car);
        }

        if($car->Cat5 == 1) {
            $ean = koppelEan::get()->filter( array('ProductID' => 993, 'AutoTypeID' => $car->ID))->first();
            $car->EAN = $ean->EAN;
            self::$Cat5->add($car);
        }

        if($car->Cat6 == 1) {
            $ean = koppelEan::get()->filter( array('ProductID' => 5195, 'AutoTypeID' => $car->ID))->first();
            $car->EAN = $ean->EAN;
            self::$Cat6->add($car);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried with foreach($cars as &$car) { } and unset($car) after the loop but that is not showing any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some deep research I found it

```
            $tempCar = clone $car;
            $ean = koppelEan::get()->filter( array('ProductID' => 993, 'AutoTypeID' => $car->ID))->first();
            $tempCar->EAN = $ean->EAN;
            self::$cat1->add($tempCar);
```